# The media player does not start playing in the background when the application has access to extended execution session

Tags: c#, uwp

This is the code for accessing extended execution session

```
public static async Task<bool> BeginExtendedExecution()
    {
        // Create new session.
        var newSession = new ExtendedExecutionSession()
        {
            Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.Unspecified,
            Description = "Timer and notifications",
        };
        newSession.Revoked += SessionRevoked;

        // Try to request access to extended session.
        switch (await newSession.RequestExtensionAsync())
        {
            case ExtendedExecutionResult.Allowed:
                session = newSession;
                return true;
            default:
            case ExtendedExecutionResult.Denied:
                newSession.Revoked -= SessionRevoked;
                newSession.Dispose();
                return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the code that does not work properly in the background:

```
private async void DigitTimer_CountDownEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var stream = await Exercises.SynthesizeExercise(settingsButton.SelectedExercise);
        mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream, stream.ContentType);
        Debug.WriteLine("here");
        mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.Play();
    }
```

I get the output "here" but the media player does not start to play. When the application leave background the media player plays the sound as if it was on all the time. And when I again send the application to the background mode, the sound plays normally.

**I have Background media playback capability in the manifest file.**

Edit: I found out that MediaPlayer can't start playing because `mediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer.AudioStateMonitor.SoundLevel == SoundLevel.Muted`
I can't change it directly because it's readonly and this value is determined by the system. So the only thing i can do is to 
play sound endlessly.

Comment: @kennyzx I'm sorry. In real code, I call an asynchronous function.

Comment: show how you register the timer’s ‘CountdownEnd’ event.

Comment: @kennyzx I have a user control "DigitTimer". I use it in mainpage.xaml:<custom:DigitTimer x:Name="digitTimer" 
                               CountDownEnded="DigitTimer_CountDownEnded"/>

Comment: @kennyzx Event works for sure because i get the output "here". I also show notifications in this event and they work fine. I think that the problem is in the media player. I'll try to do the same using background task.

Comment: From your description, I suspect this is caused by incorrect use of ‘async’. The countdownended method is declared as ‘async void’, so it is considered as completed immediately and the app is put to suspended state. Try changing async void to async Task.

Comment: @kennyzx I found out the problem and added it to the description. I think everything should work just like that, but it's very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a solution. You need to specify a MediaPlayer source value other than null before going into the background mode or the system mutes MediaPlayer's sound.

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var stream1 = await new SpeechSynthesizer().SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("");
        player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream1, stream1.ContentType);
        player.MediaPlayer.Play();

        await BeginExtendedExecution();

        await Task.Delay(3000);

        var stream2 = await new SpeechSynthesizer().SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Test.");
        player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream2, stream2.ContentType);
        player.MediaPlayer.Play();
        Debug.WriteLine(player.MediaPlayer.AudioStateMonitor.SoundLevel);
    }
```

You can check it yourself. Try this code and minimize app immediately after opening (The sound should not work):

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await BeginExtendedExecution();

        await Task.Delay(3000);

        var stream2 = await new SpeechSynthesizer().SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync("Test.");
        player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(stream2, stream2.ContentType);
        player.MediaPlayer.Play();
        Debug.WriteLine(player.MediaPlayer.AudioStateMonitor.SoundLevel);
    }
```